# How to use scatter_update update a tensorflow diagonal weight matrix

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to update a tensorflow diagonal weight matrix using scatter_update but with no luck so far. It either prompted shape mismatch or only updated along first row. It is very bizarre API behaviour. Could anyone help me out? Thanks

```
Example:
dia_mx = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.array([[1.,0.,0.],
                                             [0.,1.,0.],
                                             [0.,0.,1.]]))
new_diagonal_values = np.array([2., 3., 4.])
tf.scatter_update(dia_mx, [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]], new_diagonal_values)

Get error:
InvalidArgumentError: shape of indices ([3,2]) is not compatible with the shape of updates ([3]) [Op:ResourceScatterUpdate]

Expect new diagonal matrix:
dia_mx = [[2.,0.,0.],
          [0.,3.,0.],
          [0.,0.,4.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To update specific indices in a tensor use *`tf.scatter_nd_update()`*:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dia_mx = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.array([[1.,0.,0.],
                                             [0.,1.,0.],
                                             [0.,0.,1.]]))
updates = [tf.constant(2.), tf.constant(3.), tf.constant(4.)]
indices = tf.constant([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]])
update_tensor = tf.scatter_nd_update(dia_mx, indices, updates)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(update_tensor.eval())
# [[2. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 3. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 4.]]
```

*`tf.scatter_update()`* applies updates along the first dimension of a tensor. In this particular case it means that updates are applied for a whole row of a matrix at once:

```py
dia_mx = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.array([[1.,0.,0.],
                                             [0.,1.,0.],
                                             [0.,0.,1.]]), dtype=tf.float32)
updates = tf.constant([[2., 0., 0.], [0., 3., 0.], [0., 0., 4.]], dtype=tf.float32)
indices = tf.constant([0, 1, 2])
update_tensor = tf.scatter_update(dia_mx, indices, updates)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(update_tensor.eval())
# [[2. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 3. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 4.]]
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad for pointing it out. The doc did mention that on the second read, the doc is loose though. But I also felt the whole tensor-related APIs clumsy. Maybe just my problem(: